# Delete selected rows from DataGridView and Database

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I want to delete the selected rows from `DataGridView` and this delete should affect the database. I'm using the `Entity Framework` and that is my code which did not work.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var toBeDeleted = (int)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
    var TE = new TaskEntities();
    var UD = new userdata();
    UD = TE.userdatas.First(c => c.ID == toBeDeleted);
    TE.DeleteObject(UD);
    TE.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: You should know that _did not work_ does not work at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Is your DGV bound to any dataSource?
Is so, delete row from datasource, and then do use Update command (or update sql query) to do chnages in database.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var toBeDeleted = (int)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
     var TE = new TaskEntities();
     var userdata = TE.userdatas.First(c => c.ID == toBeDeleted);
     TE.userdatas.Remove(userdata);
     TE.SaveChanges();
     dataGridView1.DataSource = TE.userdatas;
}
```